# [NSObject : AnyObject]! and joinWithSeparator

Tags: swift, facebook-sdk-4.0

How do you get a string value(joinWithSeparator) out of the results(Dictionary) in the following function?

```
func gameRequestDialog(gameRequestDialog: FBSDKGameRequestDialog!, didCompleteWithResults results: [NSObject : AnyObject]!){
        NSLog("resoult.count: %i", results.count)
        let res = results["to"] // This is a Key Value par
        let res = results["to"] as Dictionary // Error: has no subscript members
        let res = results?["to"] as Dictionary // Error: Value of optional type 'AnyObject' not unwrapped.


...
```

The results contain this:

```
([NSObject : AnyObject]!) results = 5 key/value pairs {
  [0] = {
    key = 0x000
    value = 0x000
  }
  [1] = {
    key = 0x000
    value = 0x000
  }
  [2] = {
    key = 0x000
    value = 0x000
  }
  [3] = {
    key = 0x000
    value = 0x000
  }
  [4] = {
    key = 0x000
    value = 0x000
  }
}
```

I was looking for something like `res.joinWithSeparator(",")` to get a String with the values.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you give an example of what the results dictionary looks like? Some data perhaps, since we can see that it is `[NSObject: AnyObject]`.

Comment: Also what do you want the output to be? Maybe a string with all the values of the dictionary? Or even a string with the keys and values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make an extension to Dictionary to get a String with all the values.

Something like this:

```
extension Dictionary {
    var joinedValues:String {
        return self.values.map { String($0) }.joinWithSeparator(", ")
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
let dict = ["name":"Mike", "age":42, "gender":"male"]

let valuesAsString = dict.joinedValues  // "male, 42, Mike"
```

Of course it will only work if your values are convertible to strings with String(). If not, you would have to make a specific extension depending on the type of your values.